# What's a better way to say, "I picked up many interesting facts/points..."

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Yesterday, I watched an educational video for an essay I'm writing, and when I began writing the intro, somewhere I wrote:

> I picked up many interesting points/facts from this video that I’ve experienced in my life before.

However, I don't think this is the best way to say it because it sounds wrong, but I'm not sure what will be better to use.

Comment: I've made some edits to try and keep it on topic. Hope your question is still what you meant to ask.

Comment: would something like "learned" be too simple? Perhaps "absorbed" ? "appreciated" is another approach that in that context would imply some partial agreement as well as suggesting that "you gained something" from the video.. that the video had something to give. "I appreciated many interesting points and facts ~presented~ in this video  ~that related to~ my life experiences. . (now I'm rewriting ..sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with:

> I picked up many interesting points/facts from this video that I’ve
>   experienced in my life before.

The problem is that you're talking about *points you experienced* or *facts you experienced.*  One doesn't experience points or facts.

You need to add a phrase like "about situations" or "about things" or "on matters" after "this video":

> I picked up many interesting points from this video on situations that
>   I've experienced in my life before.